# Python script fills memory

Tags: python, psse

I'm working on a script that consumes memory cumulatively and I don't know how to solve this. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Python garbage collector is failing somehow, what is going on?

The code sample is below, some notes are following.
I suspect the culprit is `psspy` but I don't have access to its code, is there a workaround somehow?

`ierr` are all integers.
`variable1`, etc are lists containing a single list of numbers (integers, reals or complexes).

```
import psspy
psspy.psseinit(1200)

cases = []
... #Construction of a list of strings containing filenames like 'case010.sav'
faults = []
... #Construction of another list that doesn't contribute to the problem.

for filename in cases:
    psspy.case(filename) #It opens a 'case' that alters the output of the following functions
    ierr, variable1 = psspy.function1(parameters)
    ierr, variable2 = psspy.function2(parameters)
    ...
    ierr, variablen = psspy.functionn(parameters)
    ...
    for fault in faults:
        psspy.close_powerflow() #Documentation says it  
             #'Removes the current powerflow working case from PSS®E’s working memory.'
        psspy.case(filename)
        ...
        ierr, variable1 = psspy.function1(parameters)
        ierr, variable2 = psspy.function2(parametersl)
        ...
        ierr, variablen = psspy.functionn(parameters)
        ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better question for [the PssPy stackalike](https://psspy.org/psse-help-forum/questions/)?

Comment: Yes! I didn't know PssPy stackalike! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It could indeed be that there is some sort of leak in the `psspy` namespace. In order to understand more fully where the memory is being used you should use [one of the Python profilers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).